# ASP.NET : XML Viewer for website

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have a XML file , that I need to show to the users in readable format i.e in formatting.

how this can be done with ASP.net website.
Any Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Xml control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/day7x985.aspx) to perform XSL transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Actipro Software has a great and **FREE** ASP.NET control that allows you to view XML (and other content) in a syntax highlighted fashion - it's called [CodeHighlighter](https://www.actiprosoftware.com/):

[image]
<sub>(source: [actiprosoftware.com](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/Products/DotNet/ASPNET/CodeHighlighter/Images/CHOutliningSmall.gif))</sub>

It's read-only, but if that's good enough for your scenario, it's the best solution around, I think!